# Substring out of bounds exception with NSMakeRange

Tags: objective-c, macos, substring

When looping through, making a substring of every letter in a `NSString`, this exception is thrown:

```
-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

Code:

```
- (void) analyzeContent:(NSString *)content
{
    content = [content uppercaseString];
    for (int i = 1; i < content.length; i++) {
        NSString *ch = [content substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, i)]; // <-- exception
    }
}
```

Called from here:

```
- (IBAction)analyze:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.text) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CYPHERTEXT_FILE
                                                         ofType:@"txt"];
        self.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
    }

    [self.progIndicator setHidden:NO];
    [self.progIndicator startAnimation:nil];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        [self.analyzer analyzeContent:self.text];

        // When finished update UI
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.progIndicator setHidden:YES];
            [self.progIndicator stopAnimation:nil];
        });
    });
}
```

`text`-property declaration is: `@property (copy) NSString *text;`

The exception is thrown when `i = 13172` and `content.length = 26344`.

The code is run in a background thread, but `content` is not accessed by any other thread.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: looks OK. Are you changing the string in other thread?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - No, at least not intentionally. I have just started writing the program, so there's fortunately not so much code yet. I will update with more of it.

Comment: NSString *ch = [content substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]; // <-- exception

try this...  initially i =1,then it takes 2,3,4,5,6.... and crashes

Comment: @Spynet - Bingo, thanks! I though the NSMakeRange took the parameters from and to. It actually takes from and length, so when the iteration passed the half way mark, it goes out of bound. Sorry for not catching that before post.

Comment: @Slevin: I was thinking you want to take 1,2,3 characters...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was:

I though the `NSMakeRange` took the parameters index-from and index-to. It actually takes index-from and length of substring, so when the iteration passed the half way mark (see question), it goes out of bounds.

Silly...

Answer (score 3):

**Your code:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < content.length; i++) {
            NSString *ch = [content substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, i)]; // <-- exception
        }
```

initially i =1,then it takes 2,3,4,5,6.... and crashes

try like this,

`NSString *ch = [content substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)];`